# React migration from 17 to 18: Because a cookie’s SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid

Tags: reactjs

Hi i'm trying to migrate our UI app from react 17 to 18,
webpage stops loading without obvious error in chrome debug console.
The only thing i can find from "network" is Because a cookie’s SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid.

To take baby steps, the only real change i made is package.json.
No real src code change, other than root.render, useEffect call, (following 18 migration guide).

```
old
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
new
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
```

Then did "yarn install", and started the UI app.

When i try to click the buttons, the webpage stops responding.
No error msg in the "Console" in chrome debugger.
"Network" tab only shows 204 from preflight.

The only errors i can find are in "Issues" in "Network" tab.
[image]

But we don't set cookie in our UI code.
I'm only migrating from react 17 to 18.

The old index.js

```
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN}
      clientId={YOUR_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
      authorizationParams={{
        audience: YOUR_AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
      }}
    >
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </Auth0Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,

  document.getElementById("root"),
);
```

The new one is

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
...

const app = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(app);

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN}
      clientId={YOUR_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
      authorizationParams={{
        audience: YOUR_AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
      }}
    >
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </Auth0Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

For the app.js,
the old

```
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
const App = () => {
  const { isLoading, error, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const [permissions, setPermissions] = useState();
  useEffect(
    () =>
      (async () => {
        setPermissions(
          isAuthenticated
            ? decode(await getAccessTokenSilently())?.permissions || []
            : [],
        );
      })(),
    [getAccessTokenSilently, isAuthenticated],
  );
  ...
```

The new one

```
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
const App = () => {
  const { isLoading, error, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const [permissions, setPermissions] = useState();
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const asyncFn = async () => {
        setPermissions(
          isAuthenticated
            ? decode(await getAccessTokenSilently())?.permissions || []
            : [],
        );
      };
      asyncFn();
    },
    [getAccessTokenSilently, isAuthenticated],
  );
  ...
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What other steps have you taken to migrate? 17 to 18 is a major version upgrade -  breaking changes are included. Have you followed any migration guide or even this migration blog post from React? https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide

Comment: That's right, i did follow 17-18 upgrade guidelines and fix minor things like root.render. But no one mentioned cookie, at least i haven't found.

Comment: It's very unlikely that these cookie warnings are related. It seems much more likely to be related to the new ReactDOM render syntax. Could you update with that new code?

Answer (score 0):

Removing package jsonwebtoken fixed the issue !!!

It's very hard to debug this issue, we found it by comparing with another working project.